GNU Radio can't find my USRPB205
I connected my USRPB205mini-i and tried running the following flowchart

but I keep getting,

RuntimeError: LookupError: KeyError: No devices found for -----
Empty Device Address

Here's the rest
Welcome to GNU Radio Companion 3.10.1.1 

Block paths:
/usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks
Loading: "/home/bryan/Desktop/CARSE/tx and trx/trx.grc"
Done
Loading: "/home/bryan/Desktop/CARSE/tx and trx/tx.grc"
Done
Generating: '/home/bryan/Desktop/CARSE/tx and trx/tx.py'
Executing: /usr/bin/python3 -u /home/bryan/Desktop/CARSE/tx and trx/tx.py
Warning: failed to XInitThreads()
[INFO] [UHD] linux; GNU C++ version 11.2.0; Boost_107400; UHD_4.1.0.5-3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bryan/Desktop/CARSE/tx and trx/tx.py", line 265, in 
main()
File "/home/bryan/Desktop/CARSE/tx and trx/tx.py", line 243, in main
tb = top_block_cls()
File "/home/bryan/Desktop/CARSE/tx and trx/tx.py", line 109, in init
self.uhd_usrp_source_0 = uhd.usrp_source(
RuntimeError: LookupError: KeyError: No devices found for ----->
Empty Device Address
Done (return code 1)

https://kb.ettus.com/B200/B210/B200mini/B205mini_Getting_Started_Guides

I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to signal processing.
